# Julia matrix creating via slicing numbers

Tags: matrix, julia

In Julia you can create a matrix like this:

```
A = [1:3 4:6 7:9] # 3x3 Matrix
# 1 4 7
# 2 5 8
# 3 6 9
```

you can call each index of A like this:

```
A[3, 3] # 9
```

BUT this line

```
A = [1:3] #  should return 3x1 Matrix, but does not!
```

will not return a 3x1 matrix as expected! It just returns one array consisting one element!

```
typeof(A) # Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}
```

what am i getting wrong here?

thanks

Comment: My guess is you're coming from a Matlab background... be aware that Matlab and similar languages are optimised for matrices, so pretty much *everything* is a matrix or array. Julia has a fully fleshed out type system, so expect to encounter lots of types *other than arrays* that are deliberately specialised for various operations. In this case, `1:3` returns the type `UnitRange{Int64}` and so `[1:3]` creates a vector with a single element of type `UnitRange{Int64}`. The type `UnitRange{Int64}` is often used for, e.g. indexing into arrays.

Comment: @ColinTBowers thnaks, got it!

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? Do you want to create a 3x1 matrix or a length 3 vector? They are not the same thing in Julia. Most of the answers you have got address how to do the former.

Comment: @DNF well actually i just want to know why in julia one can not create a 3x1 matrix or name it a vector the same way you create higher dimension matrix? i mean in my eyes it is some how strange? i mean for example in python+numpy same way to create a matrix gives you always same result. why not in julia?

Comment: `[x]` means "make an array with `x` as its element." If `[1:3]` made a `3x1`matrix, then it would be inconsisten with that rule. The real question, I think, is whether `[a b c]` is good syntax for array concatenation.

Comment: If you write `[a]`, how can Julia figure out if you meant `vcat`, `vect` or `hcat`, whose syntaxes are like `[a; b]`, `[a, b]`, and `[a b]`? They have different results. The most common use case is `vect`, so that's what's assumed. So for concatenating one thing, you have to be explicit.

Comment: @arashjavanmard If you've had your question answered by one of the answers below, could you please mark it as the solution so that this doesn't show up as an "Unanswered question" anymore? That would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a 3×1 matrix, the correct syntax is

```
julia> hcat(1:3)
3×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
```

To do this without allocating additional space for the range (i.e. make a lazy matrix), one can do

```
julia> reshape(1:3, 3, 1)
3×1 Base.ReshapedArray{Int64,2,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{}}:
 1
 2
 3
```

The syntax you used, `[1:3]`, constructs a one-element vector of unit ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can expand a range, note that it will return a vector
A = collect(1:3)
# or
A = [1:3;]

# if you want a Matrix (1x3), transpose it!
[1:3;]' # ' makes the transpose
```